# Azure Table Storage Database Diagramming

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm wondering what the professional way is to create a database schema for a Azure Storage Tables database (not SQL Azure).

For a datawarehouse you usually make a starscheme or snowflake (OLAP cube) and for a database with a lot of transactions you'd probably make a normalized relational database (SQL Azure/SQL Server). But with Azure Storage Tables there aren't any relations to make so what's the best practice for creating a professional Azure Storage Tables database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, Azure Storage tables do not have schema.  When you save an object to an azure table, that object is just there.  You do not create schema for a table. Visualization tools, like Cerebrata's Storage Studio or Visual Studio's table viewer attempt to visualize the data in the azure table as columns, but in reality, all they're doing is showing you properties of objects as columns for convenience.

Comment: Hmmm sounds different. I'm still trying to figure it out. Like for example the standard aspnetdb.mdf database. How could you transfer it to an azure table storage variant? Just create the same objects with properties like the tables with columns? Or is a database with membershipprovider purposes not that suitable for Azure Tables?

Comment: Well, not really.  You need a different library to read from Azure Storage tables. SQL Membership provider uses stored procedures to communicate with the data store.  You can use Azure Storage Membership providers (and other libs) from this open source project: http://azureproviders.codeplex.com/

Comment: Alright I'm checking it out right now. However I see in their example project just three entities being created. SessionStateEntity.cs, RoleEntity.cs and UserEntity.cs but not any other tables that are in the aspnetdb.mdf: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa478948.asp2prvdr0102l(l=en-us).gif Is it right that it uses just this three entities? I've looked at some other classes (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudTableClient.cs for example) with Telerik Decompiler to check what happens on initialization of the membershipprovider but I can't find any other tables.

Comment: Oh on running I see just the 3 table entities being stored. Cool I guess it all works with just these 3 and some other application logic.

Comment: Remember, there are no relationships.  An object like SessionEntity can encompass everything that has to do with a session for user... no need to build relational 1-many tables and stored procedures on top of them.  This is a mindshift

Comment: Alright so it´s like the flat file in the following image (with a greater amount of redundant data than the others)?: http://i44.tinypic.com/dw6ft5.png